# JavaScript doesn't work when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I just wrote some JavaScript for my email checker. Each line of the `textarea` will be checked when the button is clicked, but it doesn't work when I put the mail list in the `textarea`.

When the button is clicked it will send each line of the mail list to `sys_api.php?email=` but there are no PHP errors.

***Can some one help me please?***

```
        function sys_brain(list, mlist) {
        list = $('#mailist').val();
        list = list.split('\n');
        var _0x7147x6 = 0;
            ajaxCall = $.ajax ({
                type:"Get",
                email: mlist,
                url: "sys_api.php?email=" + mlist,
                async: true,
                beforeSend: function(sys_loading) {
                    $('#proc-send').css('display', 'block');
                    $('#proc-done').css('display', 'none');
                    $('#result-container').css({
                        display: 'flex'
                    });
                    $('#ygdicek').html('Checking <span id=counter>' + list.length + '</span> mailist');
                    $('#mailist').attr('disabled', true);
                    $('#mailist').css({
                        opacity: '0.5'
                    });
                },
                success: function(sys_loading) {

                },
                error: function(sys_loading) {
                    var _output = document.getElementById('unknown_res');
                    _output.innerHTML = _output.innerHTML + "span class=unk_reslt" + mlist + "<br></span>";
                },
                complete: function(sys_loading) {
                    var hasil = sys_loading.responseJSON;
                    console.log(hasil);
                    if (hasil.status == 'live') {
                        var result = "[" + hasil.country + "] " + hasil.email;
                        var _output = document.getElementById('live_res');
                        _output.innerHTML = _output.innerHTML + "<span class=live_reslt>" + result + "<br></span>";
                    }
                    else {
                        if (hasil.status == 'limited') {
                            var result = "[" + hasil.country + "] " + hasil.email;
                            var _output = document.getElementById('limited_res');
                            _output.innerHTML = _output.innerHTML + "<span class=lim_reslt>" + result + "<br></span>";
                        }
                        else {
                            if (hasil.status == 'unknown') {
                                var _output = document.getElementById(unknown_res);
                                _output.innerHTML = _output.innerHTML + "<span class=unk_reslt>" + hasil.email + "(" + hasil.msg + ")</span><br>";
                            }
                            else {
                                if (hasil.status == 'invalid') {
                                    var result = hasil.email;
                                    var _output = document.getElementById('invalid_res');
                                    _output.innerHTML = _output.innerHTML + "<span class=inv_reslt>" + result + "<br></span>";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    };
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        $('#result-container').css({
                            backround: 'none'
                        });
                    }, 300);
                    var live = $('.live_reslt').length;
                    var limited = $('.lim_reslt').length;
                    var unknown = $('.unk_reslt').length;
                    var invalid = $('.inv_reslt').length;
                    $('#berapaLive').html(live);
                    $('#berapaLimited').html(limited);
                    $('#berapaUnknown').html(unknown);
                    $('#berapaInvalid').html(invalid);
                    var berapa = list.length--;
                    $('#counter').html(berapa);
                }
            });
        }

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#submit').click(function(){
                if($('#mailist').val().trim()==''){
                alert('No mailist found!');
                sys_brain(list, mlist);
            }
            });
        });
```

Comment: What’s `unknown_res`, `list` and `mlist`? Use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to find problems with your code immediately. Use the [browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) and read the errors.

Comment: `unknown_res` mean var name for unknown result, `list` is the splited mailist, and the `mlist` is the email address who will be checked

Comment: Try simplifying the problem. This may enable you to simplify the question which stands a better chance of getting an answer.